# Mongodb shell mongo: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017

Tags: shell, mongodb, powershell

It was fine 2 days ago, Now `mongod` does not work. Even `echo ps -A | grep mongo` printed nothing, yet it warns about error: "Only one usage of each socket address". How to kill that? I have also tried with different random port. How can they fail as well?

```
D:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.3\bin>mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sun Mar 03 18:10:03 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6292 port=27017 dbpat
h=\data\db\ 64-bit host=Sadaf
Sun Mar 03 18:10:03 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.3, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Mar 03 18:10:03 [initandlisten] git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2
f4a96bf08
Sun Mar 03 18:10:03 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(ma
jor=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB
_VERSION=1_49
Sun Mar 03 18:10:03 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sun Mar 03 18:10:03 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Sun Mar 03 18:10:03 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recov
ery needed
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 O
nly one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
 permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 Only one
 usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permit
ted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] now exiting
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 dbexit:
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets..
.
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sun Mar 03 18:10:04 dbexit: really exiting now

D:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.3\bin>echo ps -A | grep mongo

D:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.3\bin>
```

Comment: try running `netstat -anbo` and see if any process is bound to the same port number 27017.

Comment: If this is not a production system, just reboot :) but otherwise, you will have to track down the process holding the port and kill it

Answer (score 21):

In the command prompt type the following command

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "27017"
```

This will list all processes which are using port "27017" along with the PID.

Locate the PID using "27017". 
For example if the PID is 10580, to kill it

```
taskkill /f /pid 10580
```

Now start mongo.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Turned out I had something else running on the same port. I ran 'mongod' inside my mongo /bin/ directory to find the port. Then followed the above and killed the task. Mongo worked fine after that. Have an up vote!

Comment: @Ram Pratap I need your help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064638/how-can-i-solve-failed-to-set-up-sockets-during-startup-when-i-run-mongodb-se. Maybe you can help me

Comment: @SuccessMan I did see the other question. What you need to do is locate the pid after running `netstat -a -n -o | find "27017"` command and then kill that task using `taskkill /f /pid pid-number-from-previous-command`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

try to start mongo on a different port: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--port

to be sure what port you can use, execute the command Sriukanth Venugopalan mentioned, it will list the current ports being used.

Regards,
Moacy

Answer (score 4):

1. Open command prompt in `Administrator` mode
2. run `net stop MongoDB`

Comment: I need your help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064638/how-can-i-solve-failed-to-set-up-sockets-during-startup-when-i-run-mongodb-se. Maybe you can help me