# How can I solve " Failed to set up sockets during startup" when I run mongodb server?

Tags: mongodb, command-prompt

I had install mongodb

I try run mongodb server on command promp like this :

```
mongod.exe --dbpath=c:\mongodata
```

There exist error like this :

[image]

I try run : `netstat -a -n -o | find "27017"`

But it's the same. There still exist error

I get reference from here : [Mongodb shell mongo: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185572/mongodb-shell-mongo-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-add)

I had the reference. But it does not work

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Failed to set up sockets during startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483014/mongodb-failed-to-set-up-sockets-during-startup)

Comment: please add a dump of netstat

Comment: @profesor79 What do you mean by `a dump of netstat`? Please explain in more detail. Like the description in my question, I have answer from the link

Comment: @SuccessMan when you run `netstat -a -n -o | find "27017"` command what do you see?